# Getting the audio output of a computer

Tags: java, audio, processing

With the following code you obtain the audio input (microphone) in Processing (Java):

```
in = new AudioIn(this, 0);
```

How do I get the audio OUTPUT of the computer?

Comment: Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211484/how-do-i-capture-the-audio-that-is-being-played; Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869898/java-sound-api-capturing-sound-output-from-a-target-port and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644368/capturing-speaker-output-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You have to route the computer's (audio card's) output to a line that can be used by processing.

You can use an app like Sound flower.